# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'library' executable may have wrong permissions for ChromeDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-web-driver

I want to use the chrome webdriver to connect to "https://www.google.com". 
below is the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver  
import time  

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\faisal\\library")  
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)  
driver.get("https://www.google.com")  
driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys(" automation by name ")  
driver.find_element_by_name("blink").click()  
time.sleep(5)  
driver.close()
```

When I run the test, the following error message is displayed.Its a permission problem

```
C:\Users\faisal\PycharmProjects\firstSeleniumTest2\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/faisal/PycharmProjects/firstSeleniumTest2/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\faisal\PycharmProjects\firstSeleniumTest2\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "C:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/faisal/PycharmProjects/firstSeleniumTest2/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\faisal\\library")
  File "C:\Users\faisal\PycharmProjects\firstSeleniumTest2\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\faisal\PycharmProjects\firstSeleniumTest2\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 88, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'library' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`C:\Users\faisal\library` is not the correct path to chromedriver. Give the actual path to your chromedriver file.

Comment: actual path was : "C:\\Users\\faisal\\library\\chromedriver.exe" thanks

Answer (score 9):

The error says it all :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'library' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

In you code block you mentioned :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\faisal\\library")
```

The error clearly says your program was considering **library** as the *ChromeDriver* binary. Hence the error.

But as per the documentation of [**selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver) the call to the `WebDriver()` is as :

```
class selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver(executable_path='chromedriver', port=0, options=None, service_args=None, desired_capabilities=None, service_log_path=None, chrome_options=None)
```

So you need to change send the *Key* `executable_path` along with the *Value* as the absolute path within single qoute `''` along with the raw `(r)` switch as follows :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\faisal\library\chromedriver.exe')
```

---

### Update

As per the counter question from @Mangohero1 of-coarse `executable_path` is optional but in case you provide only the *absolute path* as per the source code provided below the *absolute path* is considered as the *Value* to the *Key* `executable_path`.

```
class WebDriver(RemoteWebDriver):
    """
    Controls the ChromeDriver and allows you to drive the browser.

    You will need to download the ChromeDriver executable from
    http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
    """

    def __init__(self, executable_path="chromedriver", port=0,
         options=None, service_args=None,
         desired_capabilities=None, service_log_path=None,
         chrome_options=None):
    """
    Creates a new instance of the chrome driver.

    Starts the service and then creates new instance of chrome driver.

    :Args:
     - executable_path - path to the executable. If the default is used it assumes the executable is in the $PATH
```

Comment: Actually if i remember correctly explicitly setting the key `executable_path` is optional. But yes, it has to be the absolute path.

Comment: @Mangohero1 Thanks, added an update as per your counter question. Let me know if any further queries.

Answer (score 2):

In case of Linux providing permission will solve the problem.

Use

```
sudo chmod +x chromedriver
```

Answer (score 0):

`driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\SQA Anas\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe")`

Please enter the complete chrome driver path like this:
 "C:\Users\SQA Anas\Downloads\chromedriver.exe"

Its works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the following to run on `Windows 10` `64 bit` and `32 bit chromedriver`:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\\Users\\My Name\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe')
```

Answer (score 0):

The executable_path should have chromedriver added at last:

```py
executable_path='/home/selenium/Linkedin-Automation/chromedriver'
```